# PyCharm: Why does `audioop` get prefered?

Tags: pycharm

Why does `audioop` get prefered, if I want to import `reverse()`?

My code contains `from django.urls import reverse` already in many files.

Why does PyCharm not look my other files and then make the currently second option the first one?

I have never used the module `audioop` in my whole life.

[image: pycharm-import-reverse-django]

Comment: FYI, [posted today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69462983).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does `audioop` get preferred, if I want to import `reverse()`?

`audioop` is a built-in module, so its stub file audioop.py exists in PyCharm's `python_stubs`.

<s>PyCharm simply lists the Auto Import suggestions in alphabetical order.</s>
PyCharm lists the Auto Import suggestions by category, in alphabetical order within each one:

1. known references from imports in the current file (more about this in its own section below)
2. first party modules
3. built-in modules ← `audioop` belongs here
4. third party modules ← `django` belongs here
5. `pip._vendor` modules

> My code contains `from django.urls import reverse` already in many files.
>
> Why does PyCharm not look my other files and then make the currently second option the first one?

Such an inference mechanism is simply not implemented in PyCharm.

PyCharm does prioritise known references from imports in the current file, with some caveats (more about this in its own section below).

## Workaround

> I have never used the module `audioop` in my whole life.

You can safely delete the file, or just change the file extension (e.g. audioop.txt).

It will be regenerated when you reopen the project in PyCharm.

## Known references from imports in the current file

PyCharm prioritises known references from imports in the current file, with some caveats.

For example, if you have `from django.urls.base import get_script_prefix` in that file, then PyCharm would suggest `reverse() from django.urls.base` (which `django.urls` exposes) since it knows `reverse` is in `django.urls.base`.

Caveat: Import references aren't suggested.
For example, having `from django.urls import path` (if you're working in urls.py) doesn't suggest `reverse() from django.urls` because `reverse` is an import reference (i.e. jumping to `django.urls.reverse` would bring you straight to `django.urls.base.reverse`, since `django/urls/__init__.py` simply imported `reverse` from `django.urls.base`).

Workaround: Alias the import, and then assign that to the original name.
For example, modify the import in `django/urls/__init__.py` from `reverse` to `reverse as _reverse` and then define the variable `reverse = _reverse`.

- Caveat of this workaround: PyCharm hints this as a `v`ariable instead of a `f`unction.

  Workaround: Wrap the function.

  ```py
  def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None):
      return _reverse(viewname, urlconf=urlconf, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  ```

Comment: "PyCharm simply lists the Auto Import suggestions in alphabetical order." thank you for explaining this. Is there a plugin for PyCharm to get a more user friendly list which uses a more intelligent ordering?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: I added a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50934